# Makefile Skipping a rule even though the filetype exists

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile with these rules.

```
all: $(TARGET)
OBJECTS = file.o
  %.o: %.c
    $(COMPILER) -c $(FLAGS) &< -o C_$(basename $@).o
  %.o: %.s
    $(COMPILER) -c $(FLAGS) &< -o S_$(basename $@).o
... The Linker is then called with *.o to link all the object files
```

I have the same filename file.c and file.s in a src directory. But make is only running the first rule for the object file. Why does it only compile once? And how can I get make to compile both file.c and file.s if they exist in my src folder?

I don't want to have to create a different object file name for a different extension. That would be silly.

Is there a way for me to compile the filename with the both .s and .c extension?

I feel like make can easily do this and I am missing something.

Thank you for the help. If I'm not clear please tell me and I will try to explain it more in depth.

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstand how Make works.

There may be many ways to build a target; Make will use *one* of them, not *all.* Anyway, your makefile violates one of [Mad Scientist's rules](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/rules-of-makefiles), in that your pattern rules *do not build what they claim to build*:

```
%.o: %.c
    $(COMPILER) -c $(FLAGS) &< -o C_$(basename $@).o
%.o: %.s
    $(COMPILER) -c $(FLAGS) &< -o S_$(basename $@).o
```

The first doesn't build `foo.o`, it builds `C_foo.o`; the second doesn't build `foo.o`, it builds `S_foo.o`. I don't know how your linking rule works, but if it depends on `foo.o`, you're in for trouble.

Try this:

```
C_%.o: %.c
    $(COMPILER) -c $(FLAGS) &< -o $@
S_%.o: %.s
    $(COMPILER) -c $(FLAGS) &< -o $@
```

Then give your linking rule whatever prerequisites you think it should have. If you want it to use both `C_foo.o` and `S_foo.o` (which doesn't sound like a good idea), then put both of them in the prerequisite list.

Comment: Is that rule #4? I guess I can have a separate filename.o for each file. It just makes my makefile incredibly large and hard to maintain. Is there anyway to force makefile to build a target with all available rules?

Comment: @Bradleybare: I don't know what *"a separate filename.o for each file"* means. Which target are you talking about? Why would you want Make to build `foo.o` with one rule, then overwrite it with another?

Comment: I don't. I just have a files called DMA2D.c and DMA2D.s because I can write the register rules in asm but the higher level stuff in c. I wanted to be able to call them both DMA2D but with a different extension. By seperate filename.o I mean DMA2D_S.o and DMA2D_C.o.

Comment: Can I somehow Compile the same filename with a different extension (ex DMA2D.s and DMA2D.c)? I still wanted to be able to use vpath. Which I can't do with wildcard. And I don't want to use wildcards in make.

Comment: I figured it out. I did not realize I could use bash in a makefile. duh what an idiot. Thank you for your patience before!